# Spellcheck API for websites

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, web-services, api

Is there an API available that allows us to POST a word and receive a boolean result, based on whether it's true or false/correct or not?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/177538)

Comment: That section states that this type of question is fine provided I have: "1.Put some effort into researching the problem" - which I have.

Comment: you could have at least stated which ones you have tried or shown your code. otherwise, this will be mistaken for a "give me teh codez" type of question.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - `Give me teh codez` lol.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Sorry about that. I try to avoid putting detail into questions these days as I seem to get bagged out when I do. Apparently some people like detail, but when there is detail, it's all just too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there's something like *exactly* what you want, but did you check out [dictionary.com's API](http://developer.dictionary.com/)?

Comment: I did actually check out a bunch of API's for dictionary sites but I haven't checked that one out yet. Will do now, thank you

Comment: No problem.  If this fulfilled your need, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted! :-)

Comment: Excellent. Looks like I'll be using Dictionary.

Comment: I didn't know `Dictionary.com` has a API for developers! Now I know one more thing~

Comment: Knowing one more thing is awesome! You are now awesome! All hail all mighty questioner!